# How to add Pods to Swift Package

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I can not found the way how to add Pods to Swift Package.

How I could add Pods to the Swift Package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CocoaPods and Swift Package Manager are two different package managers and not compatible with each other.

The shortest path is to make sure there is to create a corresponding `Package.swift` for each CocoaPods `podspec` and then use Swift Package Manager for everything (or vice versa - create a `podspec` for each Swift package).

Comment: And probably here is a reason why I can not found solution how to do it.